# Shared products DB between multiple Magento installations

Tags: multi-vendor

Multiple magento installations with PRIVATE and SHARED DB.
Products on Shared DB will be managed ONLY by me, while they (stores admins) will be able to manage their own products DB and all the rest.

So every store will feature a catalogue of products coming from 2 DBs.

Is it possible?

THanks!

Comment: Really need 2 Databases ? It's possible but will need some code! Why don't you use standard magento functionnality such as multiple storeviews / websites + handling of admin permissions ?

Comment: What functionality/feature are you wanting to implement here?  It sounds you are trying to achieve some kind of supplier login setup where suppliers can manage their own products or something along those lines, is this right?

Comment: I just want to provide an ecommerce system to book stores. Since I provide the titled DB, I need to provide it in their e-stores. They will have to manage customers, orders, ads, CMS, payments, shipments... evertyhing beside the prod catalogue because I AM the one taking care of that part.

Stores owners will also have to be able to manage their own prods db since they can find books from who ever they like in the world and sell through the e-store.

Comment: i didnt know the 2 websites were connected together. sorry